# How do I consume a web service and export the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am new to how  to consume a web service.
I use a third party app which has a report export tool.
I have built several reports and I want to automate the reports to run monthly.
The reports will export data to another app.
I was told that the only way to do this was to use their web services.
I use C# and ASP.NET (and SQL) in my app.
My question is: How do I use the information below to consume their web service and export the data?
I would like to export to  a CSV file or a table in SQL Server.
I did create a service reference and a web reference in my app.
One of the outputs you can select for their reports is ‘web service’.

When I choose web service as the destination they then provide the following info:

Report Name: CPT_Codes_WS

Web Services Page, WSDL, and DataSource for Web Services Export:
https://reportservices.CompanyName.com/reports/ExportService.asmx

Encrypted Connection String:
FakeEncryptedConnectionString__

Query for Dataset Export:

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>
https://reportservices.CompanyName.com/ExportDataSet
</SoapAction> 
<Method Namespace="https://reportservices.CompanyName.com/" Name="ExportDataSet"> 
<Parameters> 
<Parameter Name="connection" Type="String"><DefaultValue> FakeEncryptedConnectionString__</DefaultValue></Parameter> 
<Parameter Name="start_date" Type="String"><DefaultValue></DefaultValue></Parameter> 
<Parameter Name="end_date" Type="String"><DefaultValue></DefaultValue></Parameter> 
<Parameter Name="custom_param1" Type="String"><DefaultValue></DefaultValue></Parameter> 
<Parameter Name="custom_param2" Type="String"><DefaultValue></DefaultValue></Parameter> 
<Parameter Name="custom_param3" Type="String"><DefaultValue></DefaultValue></Parameter> 
</Parameters> 
</Method> 
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true"> ExportDataSetResponse{}/ExportDataSetResult{}/diffgram{}/NewDataSet{}/Table{CPT_Code,Description,Other_Code,CPT_Modifier,Service_ID,Service,Service_Description,Program_ID,Program,Pgm_Dsc,Start_Minutes,End_Minutes,Matrix_ID,Start_Age,End_Age,Claim_Format,Credential_Group,RollUp_Code,Rate,Deaf_Rate,Fixed_Units,First_Unit_Minutes,Unit_Minutes,Unit_Multiplier} 
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Comment: In what code do you call the WebService? What is happening or not happening when you do it?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you can use connected services to generate the classes you need to call the service methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: I am not sure how to call the web service from code. I created a reference and it added a connected service and a web reference to my app. I added a button called BtnUpdateCPT_Codes to my app and added a click event to it. But what do i put in the click event?

Answer (score 0):

Oh joy, it's a SOAP one..

Assuming you use VS 2019:

- Right click the Dependencies node in solution explorer
- Choose Manage Connected Services
- This appears:

[image] choose

- Put your asmx URL in the box. You might have to tack `?WSDL` onto the end of it
- Choose a namespace/set any other options. Click Finish

That's pretty much it.. Whatever you chose in the "namespace" box is where you'll find the client - say you called it AwesomeService, you'll make a `new AwesomeService.XYZSoapClient` (XYZ is derived from the service name, probably it'll be ExportServiceSoapClient in your case) and call methods on it (like ExportDataSet)

In older VS this was called "Add Service Reference" (and even older, I forget exactly, maybe Add Web Service) in the References node and the UI was a little different, but it's the same kind of thing - you give the URL, VS makes a class with a name ending in Client, it has methods with parameters that represent the actions the service exports

Comment: I am using VS 2017. Is it different? If so how?

Comment: when I added a service reference (web reference) it did create a connected service for me. The problem is I do not know what to do with the connected service/service reference. How do I use the soap query? Where do i put this? etc....

Comment: I don't know - that's for you to decide.. Where do you *want* to call the service? For example, say you'd added a service that adds two numbers, and you've put a Add button on your form and a couple of numeric up down controls.. In the AddButton_Click handler you could `resultLabel.Text = new CalculatorServiceSoapClient().Add(_numericUpdown1.Value, _numericUpdown2.Value).ToString()`, right?

Comment: The web service call requires the following:

ExportDataSet(string connection, string start_date, string end_date, string custom_param1, string custom_param2, string custom_param3)

Comment: I added a button to try and call the web service. The report has no parameters. The code is:

        protected void BtnUpdateCPT_Codes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            com.crediblebh.reportservices.ExportService ExportDS = new com.crediblebh.reportservices.ExportService();
            ExportDS.ExportDataSet("GG3nqYYB2cfN18cYlNyqcpLD0V291y1gnZawA__", "","","","","");
        }
    }

Comment: When I run the code it returns the following:
    
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The request failed with an empty response.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: I'm not well placed to respond to your query - this is a private webservice, you havent given the URL or, nor any credentials. Your code is calling the service and not getting a response. Seek help from the people who run the webservice; I can't tell you what to put into it to make it respond. If you have any query over whether VS has done its own job correctly of linking to the service, cosider linking it to a simpler service, like http://dneonline.com/calculator.asmx - you should be able to get that working and responding with simple math operations easily, to prove VS can use webservices